# Gmaps4rails : zoom not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I have the following view in my Rails code :

> <%= gmaps4rails(@map,  { "processing" => 'json', 'auto_adjust' => false, 'auto_zoom' => false, 'zoom' => 10 }) %>

I have only one marker on my map. When I display the map, the zoom is always set to the maximum, despite the options I set above. Did I forget an option ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this instead (the `gmaps` method lets you pass in options, whereas the `gmaps4rails` method does not):

```
<%= gmaps("markers" => {"data" => @map}, "map_options" => {"processing" => "json", "auto_adjust" => false, "auto_zoom" => false, "zoom" => 10}) %>
```

See http://rubydoc.info/gems/gmaps4rails/0.8.1/ApplicationHelper for documentation on these two methods (`gmaps` vs `gmaps4rails`)

Comment: Great to see I'm no more the only one to answer :)

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get zoom working by setting a center position

I did this in the controller:

```
@gmaps_options = {
  "map_options" => {
    "auto_zoom" => false,
    "zoom" => 12,
    "center_latitude" => @event.lat,
    "center_longitude" => @event.long
  },
  "markers" => {
    "data" => @event.to_gmaps4rails
  }
}
```

And then this in the view

```
<%= gmaps(@gmap_options) %>
```